# How to edit academic/research oriented CV (curriculum vitae) for industry roles

Tags: resume, job-search, job-change, careers

I have a CV I used to apply to academic/research roles. I listed everything related to research, teaching, courses, software, as well as professional experience. I am trying to see if there are any good ways/canonical approaches to modify this CV to apply for industry related jobs.

I am applying to industry roles that also may involve significant research or software engineering/machine learning, so I would like to see if I would need to re-format the CV. One thing I know is that the Professional Experience would have to come to the front and center of the CV (before school/research/teaching based on input from recruiters/resume reviewers). After that, I would like to know what other approaches I should take in re-formatting my CV for career roles. I have listed my research/projects/teaching and competition information since some roles like to see these things as well.

Comment: Is your academic experience in s. Engineering/m. Learning?

Comment: The experience is in operations research, but I have taken courses in inter-/intra-departmental courses such as financial engineering, machine learning, signal processing, and other engineering courses. For quantitative finance roles, sometimes they like to see these as well

Comment: Your teaching experience is probably not that important for industry roles, so atleast move that to the end. Courses, unless extremely relevant for the current position, are also less important IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need, for applying to commercial / industrial companies, a much shorter document called a resumé. It typically has a section for each job you have held, including academic assistantships or postdocs.

Each section should very briefly mention what you did and why. A potential employer wants to see things that will make you useful to them.

Be aware that teaching experience is not worthless to employers. Your proven ability to explain things and mentor people is valuable (but not as valuable as expertise in the job's field).

Under Education, it has a section of each degree you've taken. It may have a section for publications and patents.

You can find many good examples online to use as templates. If possible, ask a friend in industry in a field like yours to review your draft resumé.

At the end you may put the words "I will provide a complete CV on request." That clues in employers who know how to read academic CVs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do have a resume, but sometimes the CV is requested for more quantitative research roles in industry